# Button needs to be clicked twice to work - why?

Tags: android, button, onclick, fragment, onclicklistener

My issue is the Button in my activity needs to be clicked twice to make the code execute written in the onClick method.
While I am sharing my Activity code and Layout file code. Please guide me to solve the issue.

**Activity (Fragment)**

```
public class SelfFamilyInfoActivity extends Fragment {

Button btnUpdateFamily;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.self_mem_details_family_info, 
  container, false);

    try {

        btnUpdateFamily = v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateFamily);

        btnUpdateFamily.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Clicked", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return v;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
}
```

**Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/llLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnUpdateFamily"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Update Family Info"
                    android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColorWhite"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

While this fragment is being initialized in Another MainActivity.

Comment: you want double click or its working on the second click

Comment: its working on the second click. while it is supposed to work on first click.

Comment: try click from xml

Comment: do u mean to say OnClick property in button xml code?

Comment: Do you mind removing the `try-catch` around the button initialization and see if there's an actual exception thrown?

Comment: @YasinYILDIRIM : tried .. but same thing is happening.

Comment: @MilanPansuriya : on using OnClick in xml i get exception 
Could not find method btnFamilySubmit(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute
NOTE: I have declared the method in fragment also.

Comment: can you add what you tried

Comment: could you please try adding "clickable" and "focusable" params as true in xml ?

Comment: Might be worth a try, can you try onTouch instead of onClick?

Comment: @MilanPansuriya  : in XML-
            android:onClick="btnTest"
in Activity - public void btnTest(View v){
Toast....}

Comment: btnTest write in your fragment not in activity

Comment: @javabee I tested your code and it works, maybe there is another problem with the activity, can you add the code of the activity, try with other devices

Comment: Guys. It worked in first run , it didnt work again. please give more suggestions.

Comment: @Ahmed.ess : I am trying this on 3 devices i have. 
on all of them it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

For fragment it is good to use your all view click in `onViewCreated` method. May be view not prepared but you start clicking . And you use `try catch` block did you see any exception in your log. I am not sure. But you can try your click listener in your `onViewCreated` method.

**UPDATED**
try to use this code. this code working in my section

```
 Button btnUpdateFamily;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.self_mem_details_family_info,
            container, false);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    btnUpdateFamily = view.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateFamily);

    btnUpdateFamily.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Thanks brother. This Worked for me.

Comment: Welcome! @java bee

Comment: hi. I guess the problem is not solved yet. i run the app and it worked on first run while applying to the changes you suggested. and it is giving the same issue now.
buttons needs to be clicked twice to work.

Comment: buttonName.bringToFront(); try it

Comment: still the same. 
Sorry for removing the answer flag.
I am badly in need to resolve this issue.

Comment: It worked in my section well. try to use this code in you r fragment class. i updated my answer

Comment: i have changed my code according to your code. but still sometimes the button works on first click and sometimes on second click.
I think the issue is in creating the view. 
I will take some more efforts to resolve this issue. and post it here. 
thanks for the brilliant help tariqul and other friends.

Comment: i used your view. I have doubt  your activity. It will good to show your activity xml